# VBA EXCEL - Find the oldest date in a column

Tags: vba, excel

Currently working on a function, and as part of it i need to find the oldest date in a column in VBA. Have spent a while looking for solutions but cant find much. I found one line however it doesn't actually work. Ill post the code snippet I have but any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

```
Public Function SetSOWDates() As String

    Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
    Set wsCRC = Worksheets("CRC")

    Dim LastRowInCRC As Long

    LastRowInCRC = CRC.LastRowInCRC()

    LatestDate = Format(wsCRC.Max(Range("K8:K" & LastRowInCRC)), "dd/mm/yyyy")

    Debug.Print LatestDate

End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `Min`, not `Max` for the oldest date, and it's a member of `WorksheetFunction` rather than the `Worksheet`:

```
LatestDate = Format(Worksheetfunction.Min(wsCRC.Range("K8:K" & LastRowInCRC)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Good catch on the min/max issue; I totally missed that.

Comment: I actually managed to figure it out before reading this answer but much appreciated for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up worksheetfunction calls with the worksheet and trying to stuff text-that-looks-like-a-date into a long integer.

```
Public Function SetSOWDates() As String

    Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowInCRC As Long

    Set wsCRC = Worksheets("CRC")

    LastRowInCRC = wsCRC.LastRowInCRC()

    LatestDate = application.Min(wsCRC.Range("K8:K" & LastRowInCRC))

    Debug.Print Format(LatestDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")

End Function
```

There was also a typo in `CRC.LastRowInCRC()` instead of `wsCRC.LastRowInCRC()`.